# Laravel: Form add is ok . But when I want to update it gives me error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

[Controller update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIoxz.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92pRB.jpg)

If I add data in form, I can do it successfully . But whenever I want to update , it gives me error

Comment: You don't have 'updated_at' column in userinfos table. Did you delete $table->timestamps() from the migration?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require updated_at column in your Database, add this in migration :
**$table->timestamps();**
then re run the migration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save created_at and updated_at, you must to set this in you migration or add the manually.

Your migration must be soething like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('email', 250)->unique();
    $table->string('password', 250);
    $table->string('mobile', 12)->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('mobile_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('avatar', 100)->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();  ----->>>>>>> Here is what I mean!
});
```

Otherwise when it's no matter when your record is created/updated, you have to set following line at the top of your **Model** (after **use** command):

```
public $timestamps = false;
```